# How to resolved Database Exception (#2002) in Yii2 on window azure server

Tags: database, yii2-advanced-app

I got an issue with the db connection in Yii2 while doing the setup on portal.azure.com server.
I have tried to check the connection, but that works fine with the mysqli connection.
For more details please find the attachments.

**Database Exception (#2002):**

[image]

**PDOException:**

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by adding 'host=' in dsn->mysql as below:-
'dsn' => 'mysql:host=u*-****-azure-******-f.cloudapp.net;dbname=****'

Answer (score -1):

check runned or failed mysql service